# Nasm - Crinkler not importing winapi functions

Tags: winapi, assembly, linker, nasm

I've been trying to assemble this [codeproject program](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1035362/Simple-Window-With-Assembly) with [Nasm](https://www.nasm.us/) and [Crinkler](https://github.com/runestubbe/Crinkler), but every time I try to link the object file with kernel32.lib and user32.lib it gives me the following output:

```
Crinkler 2.3 (Jul 21 2020) (c) 2005-2020 Aske Simon Christensen & Rune Stubbe

Target: out.exe
Tiny compressor: YES
Tiny import: NO
Subsystem type: WINDOWS
Large address aware: NO
Compression mode: SLOW
Saturate counters: NO
Hash size: 500 MB
Hash tries: 100
Order tries: 0
Reuse mode: OFF (no file specified)
Report: NONE
Transforms: NONE
Replace DLLs: NONE
Fallback DLLs: NONE
Range DLLs: NONE
Exports: NONE

Loading window.obj...
Loading kernel32.lib...
Loading user32.lib...

Linking...

Forced alignment of 1 code hunk to 1 (including entry point).

WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'GetModuleHandleA'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'LoadIconA'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'LoadCursorA'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'RegisterClassExA'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'MessageBoxA'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'CreateWindowExA'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'ShowWindow'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'UpdateWindow'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'PeekMessageA'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'TranslateMessage'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'DispatchMessageA'
WINDOW.OBJ: START: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'ExitProcess'
WINDOW.OBJ: WindowProc: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'PostQuitMessage'
WINDOW.OBJ: WindowProc: error LNK: Cannot find symbol 'DefWindowProcA'
```

I've also tried to link it with [golink](http://www.godevtool.com/#linker) and it gives me the same errors in its format:

```
GoLink.Exe Version 1.0.3.0  Copyright Jeremy Gordon 2002-2018   info@goprog.com

Error!
The following symbols were not defined in the object file or files:-
ExitProcess
RegisterClassExA
CreateWindowExA
MessageBoxA
GetModuleHandleA
PeekMessageA
TranslateMessage
DispatchMessageA
PostQuitMessage
DefWindowProcA
ShowWindow
UpdateWindow
LoadIconA
LoadCursorA
Output file not made
```

The command lines are:

```
nasm window.asm -f win32

crinkler /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:START /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TINYHEADER window.obj  kernel32.lib user32.lib

golink window.obj kernel32.lib user32.lib
```

And in the code I have:

```
extern printf
extern ExitProcess
;all other externs

;more code
START:

push 0
call GetModuleHandleA
;more code
```

Another weird thing I noticed happens when I remove kernel32.lib and user32.lib on the linker, I get to new errors:

```
Crinkler import: _Import: error LNK: Cannot find symbol '__imp__MessageBoxA@16'
Crinkler import: _Import: error LNK: Cannot find symbol '__imp__LoadLibraryA@4'
```

Which is what I would normally expect on failed imports, normally they have "**imp**" before the name and "@number" after it.

Also, I tried importing win32n.inc and using:

```
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll
```

it failed with the nasm output:

```
error: parser: instruction expected
```

Any ideas on why it is happening and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... just changed `ExitProcess` to `_ExitProcess@4` and it worked, it seems that I need the names in this kind of strange format (I have to change all of them to see if it works), does anybody know where I can find the names in this format(changing "name" to "_name@4" won't work because the numbers are different between them)

Comment: NVM they are inside kernel32.lib and user32.lib I'm gonna have a great time finding them...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812529/nasm-symbol-at-function-declarations

Comment: Thanks @Michael, for me it was easier to look inside the lib files, where I could find the number already there, now I know where it comes from too, and knowledge is knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

Just had to replace every `extern "name"` by an `extern _"name"@"number"` that I had to obtain by looking at kernel32.lib and user32.lib.

Comment: Do you mean `extern`?  That's the NASM directive, not `external`

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right, I've edited my answer, thanks for pointing that out, Every day my memory is worse.

Comment: @ZhuSong I would mark it as an answer, but StackOverflow has decided that I have to wait two days before you can mark your own answer as correct. Tomorrow I'll do it.